# Do DC-DC converters need diode on output

Tags: dc-dc-converter

If a converter is used to charge a battery, wouldn't a reverse current damage it after it is turned off? [For example this](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/75/Datasheet_CFB400W-1948286.pdf) converter, if connected to car battery, would it work fine after turning it on/off? Or do I need a diode to prevent reverse current?

Answer (score 2):

That's a power supply, not a battery charger.

It can't be used for battery charging, and should not be connected to a battery to begin with.

So it does not really matter if you put a diode or not.

Answer (score 0):

As @Justme has pointed out, "That's a power supply, not a battery charger."

On a more general note, switched mode power supplies have an internal transformer and rectifier on the output. This inherently prevents back-feed into the power supply.

[image]

*Figure 1. D4 prevents backfeed into the power supply. Image source: [theoryCircuit.com](https://theorycircuit.com/simple-smps-circuit/).*

Comment: If you attach the output to a (for example) 12V lead acid battery, the voltage feedback circuit will draw about 1mA, which may be undesirable in the long term.

Comment: @Frog, I had considered that but couldn't think of any adverse affect. It would be 12 mW in the 1 W Zener (why so generous, I wonder?) and the optocoupler should last forever.

Comment: Well the battery would drain 1Ah every thousand hours (40 days).  For a 6Ah motorcycle battery this would be significant if there’s the intention to leave the battery in maintained for weeks or months at a time.  It may well not be a problem, but not something to dismiss out of hand.

Comment: @Frog, ah, but the power supply would be fine!